# MySQL: return field for which no related entries exist in another table

Tags: mysql, subquery, case

First, sorry for the title, as I'm no native english-speaker, this is pretty hard to phrase. In other words, what I'm trying to achieve is this:

- I'm trying to fetch all domain names from the table virtual_domains where there is no corresponding entry in the virtual_aliases table starting like "postmaster@%".

So if I have two domains:

```
foo.org
example.org
```

An they got aliases like:

```
info@foo.org       => admin@foo.org
postmaster@foo.org => user1@foo.org
info@example.org   => admin@example.org
```

I want the query to return only the domain "foo.org" as "example.org" is missing the postmaster alias.

This is the table layout:

```
mysql> show columns from virtual_aliases;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| domain_id   | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| source      | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| destination | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> show columns from virtual_domains;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| name  | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I tried for many hours with IF, CASE, LIKE queries with no success. I don't need a final solution, maybe just a hint with some explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM virtual_domains AS domains
LEFT JOIN  virtual_aliases AS aliases
ON domains.id = aliases.domain_id
WHERE aliases.domain_id IS NULL
```

LEFT JOIN returns all records from the "left" table, even they have no corresponding records in "right" table. Those records will have the right table fields set to NULL. Use WHERE to strip all the others.

---

I guess I didn't understand you correctly the first time. You have several entries in `aliases` for single domain, and you want to display only those domains that don't have an entry in aliases table that starts with "postmaster"?

In this case you are should use `NOT IN` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM virtual_domains AS domains
WHERE domains.id NOT IN (
    SELECT domain_id
    FROM virtual_aliases
    WHERE whatever_column LIKE "postmaster@%"
)
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Didn't know this would be that "easy" to implement.

Comment: Whoops, I was too fast: this query will fail if some random alias exists (I want to find domains missing exactly "postmaster@" aliases. But still thanks!

Comment: I've never thought of your option before... I like it much better than NOT IN sub-select in this case... however, there are other completely legit cases of sub-selects too.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood you the first time. Updated my answer

Comment: Great, this works as expteced. Thanks very much, and thanks to all others, your input was helpful, too.

Answer (score 2):

```
select id,domain from virtual_domains 
where id not in (select domain_id from virtual_aliases)
```

Comment: It is not checking for "postmaster@%"

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM virtual_domains vd
LEFT JOIN virtual_aliases va ON vd.id = va.domain_id
AND va.destination NOT LIKE 'postmaster@%';
```

Comment: Thanks, but this returns everything not matching "postmaster@%". I'd like to have a list of domains missing an "postmaster@"-alias (and only exactly this alias).